# customEditors property of CustomEditorConfigurer with RangeArrayPropertyEditor, Spring 4.3.3 with Spring Batch 3.0.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring 4.3.3 with Spring batch 3.0.7 and getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to
convert property value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required
type [java.util.Map] for property 'customEditors';  nested exception
is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type
[org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor]
to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditors[org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]]':
PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor]
returned inappropriate value of type
[org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor]
```

Code:

```
<bean id="customEditorConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<bean id="customEditorConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
<property name="customEditors">
    <map>
        <entry key="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.Range[]" value="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.RangeArrayPropertyEditor"/>
    </map>
</property>
```